# PIT-Cucumber plugin not finding scenarios in feature files

Tags: cucumber-java, mutation, pitest

Try to institue PIT Mutation testing in a enterprise project. Got it to do existing JUNit tests, but we also have a lot of Cucumber tests that need to be part of the metric.  Added pit-cucumber plugin to the maven project, but the output is no scenarios found. Not sure if there is some secret in the config of the plugin that I can't see.

```
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testPlugin>Cucumber</testPlugin>
                    <targetClasses>
                        <param>org.tiaa.srk.eligibility.*</param>
                    </targetClasses>
                    <targetTests>
                        <param>org.tiaa.srk.eligibility.EligibilityTestRunnerIT</param>
                    </targetTests>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.github.alexvictoor</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pitest-cucumber-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

I get this output:

> INFO : Sending 0 test classes to minion

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using Cucumber version 4.20 jars with pitest-cucumber-plugin 0.8
Everything else looks good.  You may not need to specify targetClasses and targetTests.